# How to add sdl.net window to a C# windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, sdl.net

I have a mostly complete C# winform app (it is huge, so I can't really rewrite it from scratch), and I want to add an sdl.net window to it, so as to show some of what my app does in a complex graphical manner (the sdl.net window must in some way get steady flow of data from my app, so i can't just make another project).

The problem is how do I do it? Are there any common practices for this kind of thing? Or a tutorial where something similar is done?

In a nutshell, can I add sdl.net window to a C# winform app, and if so then how?

Comment: Remember that you have to run it in a different thread

Comment: Ichiru, yes naturally, but i have no idea how to do it. Can you give a clue?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own sdl.net window class that will make use of the `SdlDotNet.Graphics.Video.SetVideoMode()` method when created, handle graphical operations internally and provide public methods to be called from your winform app.

Something like that:

```
using System.Drawing;
using SdlDotNet.Graphics;

public class SdlWindow
{
    private Surface screen; // the display Surface

    /* ctor */
    public SdlWindow(Size size)
    {
        screen = Video.SetVideoMode(size.Width, size.Height);   // create a new sdl Surface and its own window container
        Video.WindowCaption = "Sdl Window";
    }

    /* your methods */
    public void DrawRectangle(Rectangle rect)
    {
        screen.Fill(rect, Color.Red);
        screen.Update();
    }

    /* cleanup a bit */
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (screen != null)
            Video.Close();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add a reference to the SdlDotNet.dll library in your project.

Hope this helps!